# Count PostgreSQL with condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table for persons and other for visits. I need to count the visits for the month only if it was the first one. So basically get a count of visits for the month but only if your visit for the month, was the first.

Example:

```
PEOPLE:
   id   
---------
   20   
   30   
   23   

VISITS
  id     |   date
-------------------------
  20     |   09-20-2019
  20     |   10-01-2019
  23     |   10-09-2019
  30     |   10-07-2019
```

I want to know the coutning only if its the first one, on this example, the counting should equal to 2 because person with ID 20 had a past visit last month.

This is what I have so far on my query

```
SELECT * FROM visits
LEFT JOIN people ON visits.id = people.id
WHERE date_trunc('month', current_date) <= visits.visit_date AND visits.visit_date < date_trunc('month', current_date) + INTERVAL '1 month'
```

This is just giving me the visits for the month. How can I filter by only if the person doesnt have past visits.

Comment: 1 is 1.  What difference does it make if the visit that gets counted is the first, the last, or the one in the middle?  Sounds like you want `count(distinct people.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the condition by just comparing months. Add `not exists` to check whether the person had a visit before the current month.

```
select * 
from visits
left join people on visits.id = people.id
where date_trunc('month', current_date) = date_trunc('month', visits.visit_date)
and not exists (
    select from visits
    where id = people.id
    and date_trunc('month', current_date) > date_trunc('month', visits.visit_date)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand on your requirement you just need to get the person Ids that had previous visit.

my proposal is to use `dense_rank()` to based on `date_trunc('month', visit_date)`

```
select v.id from visits v
inner join 
  (select dense_rank() over (partition by date_trunc('month', visit_date) order by visit_date) as rn
  , *
  from visits) t1 on t1.id = v.id
group by v.id, t1.rn
having count(v.id) > 1
```